# merging selected date and time as date-time variables in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following code that should ask for a date and a time and then merge them together to get a date-time variable, if possible POSIXct.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTime)
ui <- fluidPage(
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(

dateInput(inputId='dateRange1',
      label = 'Enter initial date: yyyy-mm-dd'),

timeInput("time_input1", "Enter time of the initial day", value =  strptime("00:00:00", "%T"))
),

mainPanel(
  textOutput("time_output1")
)))
################
server <- function(input, output) {
vals <- reactiveValues()
observe({
vals$initial_date <-paste(as.character(input$dateRange1),strftime(input$time_input1, "%T") , collapse = " - ")
})
output$time_output1 <- renderText(vals$initial_date)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would like the class of vals$initial_date to be "POSIXct" "POSIXt", but I do not manage. I need to make operations with the dates and times. I have tried many things, among other ones I have used:

```
vals$initial_date<- strptime(vals$initial_date, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

and

```
vals$initial_date<- as.POSIXct(vals$initial_date, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

inside the 'observe', but it did not work. 
Can someone please tell me where my problem is?

thanks!

Comment: What is the output you want to get? Your code works on my laptop.

Comment: Thanks for having a look. Currently the class of vals$initial_date is character and I would like to convert it to POSIXct to operate with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time input already has the date component, we can get rid of it if you like. Note that I have added the `inherits` test to see if the object in the `reactiveValues()` is of type `POSIXct`. Also I added some `renderText` conditional so it displays full datetime oppose to just date when rendering 00:00:00

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTime)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      dateInput(inputId='dateRange1',label = 'Enter initial date: yyyy-mm-dd ', value = Sys.Date()),
      timeInput("time_input1", "Enter time of the initial day", value =  strptime("00:00:00", "%T"))

    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("time_output1")
    )))

################
server <- function(input, output) {
  vals <- reactiveValues()

  observe({
    testdatetime <- paste(input$dateRange1,strftime(input$time_input1, format="%H:%M:%S"))
    testdatetime <- as.POSIXct(testdatetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz= "UTC")
    vals$initial_date <- testdatetime

    # Check if the Time is a POSIXct object
    test <- inherits(testdatetime, "POSIXct")
    print(test)
  })

  output$time_output1 <- renderText({

    value <- as.character(vals$initial_date)
    if(nchar(value) == nchar(as.character(Sys.Date()))){
      value <- paste(value,"00:00:00 ")
    }
    value
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```